# Google Mobile Friendly Tester Issue - Preview Shown Is Very Small

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress, googlebot, css, mobile

The mobile friendliness tester is saying that my text is too small, and that clickable elements are too close together. I ensured that ALL text on the page was above 18 font to test, and Google still said it was not mobile friendly.

I think there's an issue fetching the site properly. On my site, the "screenshot" section takes up less than half the mobile preview, while on the other site (which passes mobile friendliness) it takes up the full preview.

Image for reference of the narrowness: [image: Note the "screenshot" section, the page loads very narrow.]

The url is Chromatin.net, running on Wordpress with Astra theme and default editor.

All of the resources on the page were loaded successfully according to the "more info" section.

Comment: Maybe you need to post a minimal version of your css and html here

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that it is because your `<body>` element doesn't have a width set.

Try adding:

```css
body {
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

If that doesn't change anything (despite poor it being poor practice):

```css
body {
    min-width: 100% !important;
}
```

This is definitely a shot in the dark, but the way you solve this problem is by taking many shots in the dark until something works.

Look for things that don't have width applied, check your break points, make sure that the CSS [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) isn't broken anywhere, and in general make sure your html is well formed (use the [w3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/)).

You can see what is likely your issue by toggling between different devices in dev tools:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried adding both of those and also adding to images and no luck unfortunately

Comment: @Tman Sorry to hear that. Did you ever solve the problem? I added a bit to my answer.